# Virtualize an ItemsControl within a StackPanel?

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollview

I'm trying to achieve virtualization for an ItemsControl that is placed within a StackPanel. The goal is to have a smooth scrolling experience for the entire page, including the ItemsControl, without the appearance of a second scrollbar specifically for the ItemsControl.

Could anyone provide guidance or suggestions on how to accomplish this? Any code examples or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

The example below illustrates the issue I'm facing.

```xml
<ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" >
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Header" />
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                          VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"
                          VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="An item" Margin="30,100,30,100" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel  IsVirtualizing="True"
                                                 VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"
                                                 VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
            <TextBlock Text="Some other Elements" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

When virtualization is disabled, it functions as expected, but when dealing with a large number of items, it becomes quite buggy. Is there a way to achieve the same behavior while still utilizing virtualization?

```xml
 <ScrollViewer >
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Header" />
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="An item" Margin="30,100,30,100" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
            <TextBlock Text="Some other Elements" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Putting scrollable into scrollable makes sens only when innr scrollable would have defined size obviously you need to have something bigger in something smaller to scroll...